# calling web service from jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to call a web service from jQuery, when I put the breakpoint the following code is hitting, but its not reaching the web service......is there anything wrong with this code?

```
function searchItems() {

$("#txtSectionName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DataService.asmx/SearchSections",
            data: "{'searchTerm' : '" + $("#txtSectionName").val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.Name
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

}

Comment: The data you send is not JSON. In JSON, keys and string values must be enclosed in double quotes. The web service might therefore fail to process the request.

Comment: @OP can you share the web service method code ...

Comment: thanks for ur response Felix Kling and 3nigma, its working fine now....sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data is malformed. jQuery will take care of JSON encoding. Just pass an object:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DataService.asmx/SearchSections",
            data: {searchTerm: $("#txtSectionName").val() },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.Name
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
```

Comment: jQuery won't convert this to JSON. It will create a query string, like `searchTerm=value`, not JSON.

Comment: Not a query string, since this is a POST request. But you're right, not JSON exactly. I meant nested url encoded, which Rails for instance decodes as a Hash. But it depends what you have on the server side...

Answer (score 1):

have you configured the web service to accept the requests from cross domains, see [**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), also try using `jsonp` as the `dataType` that ***may*** resolve the problem... also web services normally serve the `GET` requests